# Unable to build Awstats report - permission denied on awstats.pl

Tags: permissions, centos, perl, nginx

I just installed a fresh copy of Awstats 7.1 on my server running CentOS 6.3 and nginx. When I try to run this command to generate the report:

```
/usr/local/awstats/tools/awstats_buildstaticpages.pl -update -config=mydomain.com -dir=/srv/apps/mydomain/awstats -awstatsprog=/usr/local/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/awstats.pl
```

I get the following error:

```
sh: /usr/local/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/awstats.pl: Permission denied
```

**What I've Tried**

- chmod 755 /usr/local/awstats
- running the command with 'su -'
- changing user/group to 'nginx'

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should show more details. what are the permissions on awstats.pl, as which user are you executing it and so on?

Comment: Ah I think you hit the nail on the head there. As simple as it seems, I overlooked the actual permissions on awstats.pl - After chmod-ing awstats.pl it seems to be running properly! If you want to post your response in more of an answer format I'll be happy to accept it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the permissions of awstats.pl are not set to be executable. Your `chmod 755 /usr/local/awstats` is not recursive to also apply on awstats.pl.

Comment: Thank you :) after applying the chmod to awstats.pl it will now run without error.